# Central Limit Theorem and Convergence

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I'm trying to approach the following question:

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1} ^\infty$ be a sequence of identically distributed random variables, with $\mathbb{E}(X_i)=0$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$.

For all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $i+2\le j$, $X_i,X_j$ are independent.

Let $Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

I'm trying to understand why can't I use the CLT here to say that by separating $\{X_i\}_{i=1} ^\infty$ to $\{X_{2i}\}_{i=1} ^\infty$ and $\{X_{2i+1}\}_{i=1} ^\infty$, we can conclude that

$\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\overset{\text d}{\to}Z$

Comment: But it looks like you are given pairwise independence, which doesn't imply mutual independence

Comment: @Golden_Ratio You are right. Maybe this is an explanation: The series of odd indices converges to Z, and so the series of even indices, so the whole summation converges to 2Z?

Comment: But I don't see how you can even apply CLT to the series with odd indices because you are only given independence between each pair of odd-indexed random variables instead of mutual independence between them.

Comment: Also, even if you could apply CLT to each separate series, the limit (in distribution) of a sum of two sequences of random variables is not generally the sum of their limits (in distribution).

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Oh! I got it now, thank you so much!

Comment: okay, no prob !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say can be true, for example when the $X_i$ are all independent and identically distributed.  But it does not need to be true.

Let's suppose as a counter-example:

- we have sequences of $Y_i$ and $W_i$ all i.i.d. $N(0,\sigma^2)$
- $X_{2j}=(Y_j+W_j)/\sqrt{2} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$
- $X_{2j+1}=(Y_j+W_{j+1})/\sqrt{2} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$
- and each $X_j$ is independent of the others which are not its immediate neighbour

Then $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{j=1}^{n/2} 2 X_{2j} \overset{\text d}{\to} N(0,2\sigma^2)$ rather than $N(0,\sigma^2)$ as $n$ increases